# How to open the edit contact view of my android phone book

Tags: android, android-contacts

I have a program that reads the contacts and displays then in a list view .
On clicking the list item ,I should direct the user to the default edit contact view of my android device for that particular contact

Comment: The Android documentation has a [tutorial lesson](https://developer.android.com/training/contacts-provider/modify-data.html) which shows you exactly how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Just pass list item to modify intent.

Find example here https://developer.android.com/training/contacts-provider/modify-data.html